# slurm: unable to get job's information using scontrol

Tags: slurm, sacct

When I run following command I am able to see bunch of slurm jobs. Since I can see them, I believe their log should be saved.

```
$ sacct --format="JobID,JobName%30"                          
       JobID                        JobName
------------ ------------------------------
3            19kuX6ge4WzE2cyRtAUozP1SSE9HR+
3.batch                               batch
4            19kuX6ge4WzE2cyRtAUozP1SSE9HR+
4.batch                               batch
5            19kuX6ge4WzE2cyRtAUozP1SSE9HR+
5.batch                               batch
9.batch                               batch
2                                    run.sh
2.batch                               batch

$ sacct --jobs=4                                             
       JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
4            19kuX6ge4+      debug      alper          1  COMPLETED      0:0
4.batch           batch                 alper          1  COMPLETED      0:0
```

---

Afterwards, when I do: `scontrol show job <job_id>`, I won't able to return the complete job's information.

```
$ scontrol show job 4                                       
slurm_load_jobs error: Invalid job id specified
```

What may be the reason for this? Is there any alternative way to fetch the job's information such as its `RunTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scontrol` only shows information about currently running, or recently finished, jobs. The "recently finished" time depends on the installation but is 5 minutes by default (I think). `sacct` returns information from the accounting database, so works for all jobs.

Comment: Can I set `"recently finished` time to lets say 365 days or infinite? Since `scontrol` seems like returns much for information I want to able to use it all the time @ciaron

Comment: Should I set `PURGE_COMP` variable in the `slurm.conf` file?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head if there's a parameter in `slurm.conf` to control the timeout, but I suspect not. If I remember correctly, the `scontrol` data is held in memory on the `slurmctld` machine, and can get quite large (several GB over time) and needs to be purged to disk/database. You may find the information you need in `sacct` by setting the output format string for it. There's a lot more there than the default data.

Comment: PS `PURGE_COMP` is only for reservations, IIRC.

Comment: As understand its better to keep it 5 minutes as its default time to delete those

Comment: The parameter is `MinJobAge`